# Calculate the volume of water in glass over time.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics, volume

[image]

For A) I found that volume should be defined by [image] But I got no idea what to do in b) and c)

Comment: To expand at the front of "b)":  When the height of the water in the glass is $h$, calculate the surface area of the water that is in contact with the air (i.e., do not include the area in contact with the glass).  Use this to calculate the rate of evaporation when the water is at height $h$ using the given specific rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you well have shown, the volume of water inside the glass is given (note that $h$ is a function of time):

$$V(t) = \frac{\pi h^2(t)}{2}. $$ On the other hand, the surface area exposed to the air by water is given by:

$$A_s = \pi r^2(t),$$ where $r$ is the instant radius of the glass when the height of water is $h(t)$. This two quantities are related by $h = r^2$ since the shape of the glass is the given parabola $y = x^2$. You can readily show that $A_s = \sqrt{2 \pi V}$ by elementary substitution. Since we are given the rate of evaporation per unit of volume **and** unit of area (exposed surface), $q$, we have that:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = q A_s,$$ which readily yields to the desired expression for $\dot{V}(t)$: $\dot{V} = -q \sqrt{2\pi V}$, which is a separable differential equation, to be integrated as follows:

$$ \int^{V=0}_{V=V_0}  \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\sqrt{V}} = - q \sqrt{2\pi} \int^{t=t_F}_{t=0} \, \mathrm{d}t,$$ where $V_0$ is the volume of water at $t=0$, i.e., $V_0 = \pi h^2(0)/2$, and $t_F$ is the time you are being asked to compute.

I hope you find this helpful.

Cheers!